# Is set $A$ transitive if $A$ only have urelement (or have urelements)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example, is $A=\{-1\}$ a transitive set?

In wiki, it is said that:

A set $A$ is called transitive if either of the following equivalent conditions hold:

whenever $x ∈ A$, and $y ∈ x$, then $y ∈ A$.

whenever $x ∈ A$, and $x$ is not an urelement, then $x$ is a subset of $A$.

It seems $A$ satisfies the condition.

but we can also prove that set $A$ is transitive if and only if $A ⊆ P(A)$

And $A=\{-1\} ⊆ P(A)$ is $F$, because $P(A)$ is $\{\emptyset, \{-1\}\}$, so $A$ is not transitive

something was wrong, but I don't know what is it.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $A$ is transitive if and only if $A \subset P(A)$ *if* $A$ does not contain any urelements, but your $A$ does contain an urelement.